# Score using gauss decay function

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a none-symmetric decay function ?

If the `field` is `>= origin` then the resulted score is `1`.
And the decay happen the same way when approaching `scale`.

I guess then the `>=` would be if `scale < origin`, otherwise it would be `<= origin` if `scale > origin`.

[image: Looking at this image]

From this image, i just want the left part of the hump and have the right part flat.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
"filter": {
    "range": {
        "FIELD": {
            "lte":[ORIGIN]
        }
    }
},
"gauss": {
    "FIELD": {
        "origin": "ORIGIN",
        "scale": "SCALE ( SCALE < ORIGIN )",
        "decay": DECAY
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler one ?